# Can I use local jars for Java Web start application?

Tags: java, deployment, java-web-start, jnlp

**Background** :

We are using Java WS for deployment successfully. 
Recently we have adopted one new third party jar.
Newly adopted jar size is greater that 40MB. 
Application size before adopting this third party was only 8MB.

**Problem:**

Customer has approx 1000 machines and when they hit jnlp and launch the application , All client machines tries to download all jars first time (lazy downloading). This downloading takes all the bandwidth and slows down the downloading (Affecting their peak sales time)

**Solving approach**

Deliver third party jar by making it executable.(jarName.exe)
Mention third party jar name in jnlp. 
If mentioned jar name is already installed on desktop then refer that jar from local and don't download from JNLP server.

**Technical Problem**

Can we use local jars for Java Web start application?

If yes how can Java WS can refer local jar?

Comment: *"Can we use local jars for Java Web start application?"* Yes, by loading them using an `URLClassLoader`, but you lose auto-update ability. BTW - do you realize that JWS itself is deprecated in Java 9?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks , I will check with URLClassLoader option. Our installer will take care of auto-update ability.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have tried on this. It seems I need to give "createClassLoader" permission in Java.policy file and it is  dangerous.  Is there any other way? Or  Am I missing something while trying with URLClassLoade ?

Comment: *"It seems I need to give "createClassLoader" permission in Java.policy file"* No, editing policy files were never a really good approach. By the time an app. is deployed, it either comes with no security manager (in which case policy files are irrelevant and the code is running 'dangerously'. Or it has a security manager that needs to be satiated with digitally signed code that has the permission (when prompted) of the user in order to run. If the app. needs to be signed for deployment, you might as well sign it during development, again editing a policy file is unnecessary. But..

Comment: .. you seem to be ignoring the bigger problem, in that **JWS itself is deprecated in Java 9**. And guess what? It is exactly the security problems caused by running code from external, sometimes malicious, sources that prompted Oracle's decision to drop support for jamming Java applets into web pages, or downloading & launching applications & applets via JWS. It is a security nightmare.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks Andrew , I will check with Signed Jars approach. We are thinking on changing technology stack for further development.

Comment: @AndrewThompson ,Thanks ,  I am able to load local jars by modifying class path using URLClassLoader and reflection.